# Java Reflection passing parameters

Tags: java, reflection

HI,

I have methods each of them requires integer ,string respectively. I read the inputs from my xml file. I will not be aware of what the type of inputs it will be. I am using reflection to invoke the method. I read the xml and store it as string. I invoke the method by passing in the parameter. One of the method expects an integer, but I pass in string. When I try to do the getType and cast, it is throwing class cast exception.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Priya.R

Comment: As Gurcel mentioned you can't do this but there are options. Help us understand little bit more on what is the actual requirement and if possible share a sample xml doc and also a sample of the object/code you want to build

Comment: show your code then we can give you some idea

Answer (score 4):

Java is strongly typed language. You can not pass a string to integer expecting method. You should convert string to integer, you can use Integer.parseInt() ..

Answer (score 0):

If all inputs are Strings in the XML file, then there really is no difference between an XML file and a normal text file, is there?

The main problem is the representation of data types: you are not using XML as it's meant to be.  XML files should represent the particular data type an input has.  For example, a person's age should be represented as an `int`.  You lose type semantics when you encode everything as a String.

As for actual code, use the `XMLEncoder` and `XMLDecoder` java classes located [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html), respectively.

Basically, you'll do something like:

```
XMLEncoder encoder = new XMLEncoder();
XMLDecoder decoder = new XMLDecoder();
```

Encoding (aka: Storing the data to the XML File)
 - Write the first input as an integer type (`encoder.writeInt(someIntValue)`)
 - Write the second input as a String: `encoder.writeString(someStrValue)`
 - etc

When decoding, you decode an integer first, then a String, etc.